# Split text inside list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have the following list of lists:

```
db=[['CAGAAGT'],['TGACAG'],['GAAGT']]
```

I need to split the internal text of each sublist so that it looks like this:

```
db=[['C','A','G','A','A','G','T'],['T','G','A','C','A','G'],['G','A','A','G','T']]
```

I have tried the following code but an error appears, saying: `list has no attribute .split()`

```
db = [e.split() for e in db]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? String is already a sequence type, so you can access each index by - well - index. _"s[i] - ith item of s, origin 0"_ - [Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

Comment: When faced with such an error, always try printing out the intermediate results. Then you would have seen your list comprehension only goes one level deep – the individual list items, which indeed cannot `split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
db=[['CAGAAGT'],['TGACAG'],['GAAGT']]

db = [list(elem) for lst in db for elem in lst]

print(db)
```

Output:

```
[['C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'T'], ['T', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'G'], ['G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'T']]
```

Answer (score 1):

`split` can be applied on strings only but you are trying to apply it on `e` which in your case is a list.

Try instead:

```
db = [list(e[0]) for e in db]
```